# Expression show or hide visibilty on SSRS my Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to hide the entire month in every column with column visibility of a table. Is there any expression to hide the column with condition is 
if my month column < my paramater (transdate) will show, and also the otherwise. 
 Please help Thank You So Much

```
=(Count(Parameters!Dataset1_Periode.Value) < IsDate("1/12/year(Parameters!Dataset1_Periode.Value"), True, False)
```

---------OR----------

```
=IIf(Fields!SaldoNBVBulanFebruari.Value >= Parameters!Dataset1_Periode.Value,True ,False)
```

---------OR----------

```
=Not(Parameters!Dataset1_Periode.Value = IsDate"1,12,year(Parameters!Dataset1_Periode")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never want to show data after a certain date, the most efficient approach is to simply filter it out of your dataset based on the parameter and use a matrix to programmatically generate the columns based on your data.